# Async warning puzzles me

Tags: c#, asynchronous, warnings

This isn't a debugging type of question, I'm just looking for a specific bit of education within the field of asycnchronous programming, a field I'm admittedly not at home in, here.

I'm writing a program and I needed it to periodically make a call while also performing its other functions. I looked up how to write an asynchronous method to achieve this, and actually got it to work.

What puzzles me is that when I called it from my Main method, I got a warning saying that I should use the await keyword to get the program to wait for the method call to complete, otherwise I might not get the expected behavior, which was weird to me. The way I figure, the very point of writing an async method is to get it running, and then move on without waiting for it to finish, so heeding the warning would defeat the purpose. On the other hand I'm not arrogant enough to assume I know better than the professionals who developed Visual Studio and added the warning, so there must be more cases where adding the await keyword makes more sense than not.

My question is: how are asynchronous methods usually used that warrant heeding this warning?

Edit: People requested code and the specific text of the warning, so:

The async method:

```
public static async Task FindPairs(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
            while (true)
                {
                lock (relevantVariable)
                    {
                    doStuffEveryInterval();
                    }
                await Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
```

And the warning is this: "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.   The current method calls an async method that returns a Task or a Task and doesn't apply the await operator to the result. The call to the async method starts an asynchronous task. However, because no await operator is applied, the program continues without waiting for the task to complete. In most cases, that behavior isn't what you expect. Usually other aspects of the calling method depend on the results of the call or, minimally, the called method is expected to complete before you return from the method that contains the call.

An equally important issue is what happens to exceptions that are raised in the called async method. An exception that's raised in a method that returns a Task or Task is stored in the returned task. If you don't await the task or explicitly check for exceptions, the exception is lost. If you await the task, its exception is rethrown.

As a best practice, you should always await the call.

You should consider suppressing the warning only if you're sure that you don't want to wait for the asynchronous call to complete and that the called method won't raise any exceptions. In that case, you can suppress the warning by assigning the task result of the call to a variable."

Comment: This pattern is defined as `Async/Await` for a reason. This is one of the usually suggested readings when getting started: [Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). This one also: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Posting the code you're using would be good too.

Comment: If you're learning about asynchronous programming and you have a Main method, that means you're trying to make an asynchronous console app. Normally beginners in a thing start with console apps, but for async it's easier to start with a GUI application because GUIs are naturally asynchronous.

Comment: The error is probably indicating you are using the return value from the asynchronous method without waiting.  Usually I use a WaitHandle (semaphore) in the code so the asynchronous method can signal when operation is completed.

Comment: Without that [mcve] we are guessing as to what your code looks like, and what the message is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the message is here, full length. _Where_ it comes form is the puzzle.

Comment: Eiter `doStuffEveryInterval` is async or the message comes from the place wher you call `FindPairs`. Always post full, compiling code and point out to which line an error is referring,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The way I figure, the very point of writing an async method is to get it running, and then move on without waiting for it to finish

Then why did you `await` the `Delay`, if that's what you believe?  The `Delay` returns a task; you started that task, surely you want to move on before it finishes, and just do the next loop iteration again?

Of course not.  That would *defeat the entire point of the delay*, if it ran asynchronously and completed with no one waiting for it.

What then does `await` mean exactly?  It means what it says: **asynchronously wait**.  That is:  **this workflow cannot continue until this task is complete, so if it is not complete, go find other work to do and come back later**.

That's why normally the *caller* of your async method would `await` the result.  The caller is calling you asynchronously because they believe that the workflow will take some time to complete, and they can let **their caller** do more work while *they* are waiting asynchronously for your method to complete.

That's what you would *normally* do, but your method is not normal.  **Your method never completes normally!** If you did `await` this method you'd be waiting until it *threw*, (because it was cancelled) not until it *completed normally*, because it does not complete normally!

So an `await` of the task returned by your method would likely in practice be to wait forever, which is not what you want.

So you can ignore or suppress the warning in this case.  But in the normal case, **you're calling a method because you either want its side effects or its result**, and you can't continue your workflow until you get it.  So you `await` the task, so that **your caller** can do more work while you're waiting for **your callee's** workflow to complete.

Make sure that is *absolutely* clear before you write more async code. **`await` is the sequencing operation on asynchronous workflows.**  It means "this workflow will not continue until this task is complete; go find something else to do while you're waiting and come back when we can proceed".

Compare that with a "normal" call to a normal method.  `x = foo();` means "This workflow will not continue until the call to `foo` is complete; do nothing but run `foo` to completion". We are so used to calls being *synchronous waits for a result* that we don't even think about it anymore.

---

This question points out a larger design issue with the C# type system. Non-generic `Task` is logically "asynchronous void"; that is, the workflow *completes*, but does not complete with a *value*.  **C# does not have a type system concept for methods which never return normally but might throw**.  You could imagine a special version of `void`, maybe `void never`, and it would be an error in such methods to return or have a reachable end point.

Your workflow is logically a "never task" -- it is an asynchronous workflow that does not complete normally. If the compiler knew that then it could suppress the warning (and it could produce warnings on *synchronous* calls to `never void` methods that had unreachable code after them.) But the compiler doesn't know that because this concept isn't in the type system in the first place.  Logically it could be, but I think the C# team has more pressing concerns.